# How to change x- and y-axis ticks with categorical variables in Python matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot the average price (numeric variable) of cars against two categorical variables, body-size ("convertibe", "hardtop", "hatchback", "sedan", "wagon") and drive-wheels ("4-wheel drive", "front wheel drive", "rear wheel drive") in a heatmap.

Dataframe:

```
   drive-wheels   body-style         price
0           4wd    hatchback   7603.000000
1           4wd        sedan  12647.333333
2           4wd        wagon   9095.750000
3           fwd  convertible  11595.000000
4           fwd      hardtop   8249.000000
5           fwd    hatchback   8396.387755
6           fwd        sedan   9811.800000
7           fwd        wagon   9997.333333
8           rwd  convertible  23949.600000
9           rwd      hardtop  24202.714286
10          rwd    hatchback  14337.777778
11          rwd        sedan  21711.833333
12          rwd        wagon  16994.222222
```

Using this code:

```
df_test = df[["drive-wheels", "body-style", "price"]]
df_grp = df_test.groupby(["drive-wheels", "body-style"], as_index=False).mean()
print(df_grp)
df_pivot = df_grp.pivot(index="drive-wheels", columns="body-style")
print(df_pivot)
plt.pcolor(df_pivot, cmap="RdBu")
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("body-style")
plt.ylabel("drive-wheels")
plt.show()
```

I get the following result:
[image]

However, I want to have both axes ticked with their categorical values, as in here:
[image]

How can I label the ticks in categorical values?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html

Comment: I don't see the part in your code that is creating these plots. Are you sure this is the code that produces this?

Comment: @MattR Excuse me, you're right. I edited it right in.

Comment: Can you post your df?

Comment: for ticks use xticks in plt and then in labels pass your labels as a list https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Comment: The link in @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment shows it, and also https://books.google.de/books?id=14d0DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=ticks+categorical+variables&source=bl&ots=JGMZwHeHQh&sig=ACfU3U1IWCYc1ZtdT83OKiBka3DDC9ex_Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR0NHOlvTmAhVF5aQKHSsbDmgQ6AEwD3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=ticks%20categorical%20variables&f=false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily be done using [Seaborn](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwin7ID6l_TmAhUXUd4KHfGMBW8QFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fseaborn.pydata.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw0GhFbgBpk8OwHfgpvMyxJm) library:

Remove the plt section of your code and insert this code instead:

```
import seaborn as sns

df_pivot = df_pivot.fillna(0)
sns.heatmap(df_pivot, cmap="RdBu")
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to click on the checkmark beside my answer if this solves your problem. :)

Comment: One sidenote: in order to keep the axes not rotated, use: plt.yticks(rotation=0) :)